# How to make this design using css flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Css Flex Box Problem
[image]

Can anybody help me out through this problem

```js
$(".default_option").click(function(){
  $(".dropdown ul").addClass("active");
});

$(".dropdown ul li").click(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(".default_option").text(text);
  $(".dropdown ul").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #e4eefa;
}

.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.wrapper .search_box{
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -10px #b3c6ff;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown{
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 2px solid #dde2f1;
  color: #9fa3b1;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown .default_option{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 6px -10px #b3c6ff;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul.active{
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:hover{
  color: #6f768d;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-color: #5078ef transparent transparent transparent;
}

.wrapper .search_box .search_field{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .search_box .search_field .input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 38px;
  color: #6f768d;
}

.wrapper .search_box .search_field .fas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #5078ef;
  cursor: pointer;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #9fa3b1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
 color: #9fa3b1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #9fa3b1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search_box">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="default_option">All</div>  
            <ul>
              <li>All</li>
              <li>Recent</li>
              <li>Popular</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="search_field">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code is given below : https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn/pen/qBBwNbB

Comment: please add your code in your question not in comments. Please explain better where is your problem

Comment: I am not able to make the search box and filter exactly like this in the image @Sfili_81

Comment: Add your problem in the question by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

Just add `left` instead `rigth:10px` to the icon.

```js
$(".default_option").click(function(){
  $(".dropdown ul").addClass("active");
});

$(".dropdown ul li").click(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(".default_option").text(text);
  $(".dropdown ul").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #e4eefa;
}

.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.wrapper .search_box{
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -10px #b3c6ff;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown{
  width: 150px;
  border-right: 2px solid #dde2f1;
  color: #9fa3b1;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown .default_option{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 6px -10px #b3c6ff;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul.active{
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown ul li:hover{
  color: #6f768d;
}

.wrapper .search_box .dropdown:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-color: #5078ef transparent transparent transparent;
}

.wrapper .search_box .search_field{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .search_box .search_field .input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 40px;/* modified */
  padding-right: 38px;
  color: #6f768d;
}

.wrapper .search_box .search_field .fas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;/* modified */
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #5078ef;
  cursor: pointer;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #9fa3b1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
 color: #9fa3b1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #9fa3b1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="search_box">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="default_option">All</div>  
            <ul>
              <li>All</li>
              <li>Recent</li>
              <li>Popular</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="search_field">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```